# New Nexus 7 not appearing on Eclipse/AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-virtual-device, nexus-7

I am having trouble connecting a Nexus 7 to Eclipse... and really lost about what to do to get it running. OS of my Computer is Windows 7 64 Bit.
Another Nexus 7, exactly same android-version, but with less memory, was successfully connecting previously; I have no idea if that could be the cause of the problem? Somehow, none of the million topics about this solve my troubles. 
What I already did:

- Nexus 7 is in Developer Mode
- USB Debugging is Active
- I am connecting as PTP-device
- It does show up when I run adb devices on commandline. It sucessfully DISappears from adb devices when I unplug it, kill the adb server, and reboot
- Despite all this, if refuses to appear as a device in AVD Manager!

Strangely, an emulator I deleted weeks ago still appears in adb devices, but at least it is offline...
Any ideas about what I missed?

Comment: Argh.... ok, it worked now. For everyone who is as blind as me: it is not SUPPOSED to appear in AVD-Manager, but it WILL appear as device on Eclipse! Never mind my silly question, it works now :).

Answer (score 5):

Google hasn't taken the "developer" out of its Nexus line, and it's not going to anytime soon. But the settings have been hidden from casual view in the settings menu. Here's how to get them back:

1. Go to the settings menu, and scroll down to "About phone." Tap it.
2. Scroll down to the bottom again, where you see "Build number." (Your build number may vary from ours here.)
3. Tap it seven (7) times. After the third tap, you'll see a playful dialog that says you're four taps away from being a developer. (If only it were that simple, eh?) Keep on tapping, and *poof*, you've got the developer settings back.

Here are the links

[Restore the Developer Options menu in Android 4.2](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57549207-285/restore-the-developer-options-menu-in-android-4.2/)

[How to enable developer settings on Android 4.2](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42)

Comment: I already did that... a pity somehow, or I could blame that oversight ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update Drivers for your device

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Device Manager (Right click my computer and select manage)

Uninstall the Android Composite ADB Interface (delete driver) so the Nexus 7 will be displayed as Other Devices when you re-connect it. Select it and choose to update driver software with a driver you select yourself like android/extra/google/usb_driver or a downloaded driver from ASUS http://support.asus.com/download/ModelList.aspx?SLanguage=en&keyword=nexus%207&type=1

worked for me...